# how to feed a view from a webservice that returns a JSON?

Tags: json, sql-server

Developers have created a webservice that returns a JSON with employee data, I need to feed or fill a view with his data.

New business requirements require us to prevent direct DB to DB connections so I'll have to do without linked servers :(

```
USE [test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EMP]
AS
BEGIN

    set nocount on
    SET FMTONLY OFF

    DECLARE @status int
    DECLARE @responseText as table(responseText varchar(max))
    DECLARE @res as Int;
    DECLARE @url as nvarchar(1000) = 'http://websrvtst2:8086/ENFER_API/api/DatosEmpleado'
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0', @res OUT
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @res, 'open', NULL, 'GET',@url,'false'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @res, 'send'
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @res, 'status', @status OUT

    INSERT INTO @ResponseText (ResponseText) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @res, 'responseText' 
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @res


    DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @json = responseText FROM @responseText


    SELECT * FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json)--, N'$.elements')
    WITH (   
         [planta] nvarchar(max) N'$.planta'   ,
          [codempleado]   nvarchar(max) N'$.codempleado',
          [Sexo]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Sexo',
          [FechaNac]   nvarchar(max) N'$.FechaNac',
          [FullName]   nvarchar(max) N'$.FullName',
          [Plaza]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Plaza',
          [Identidad]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Identidad',
          [ISSS]   nvarchar(max) N'$.ISSS',
          [Razon_Social]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Razon_Social',
          [Departamento]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Departamento',
          [Jornada]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Jornada',
          [Unidad]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Unidad',
          [Celda]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Celda',
          [Operacion]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Operacion',
          [Make]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Make'
    ) 

    RETURN 0

END
```

when executing : EXEC [TEST].[DBO].EMP it returns the data in grid form

I'm expecting to be able to select a view and get that grid in return.

Comment: What is you actual question here?

Comment: You are receiving data from a webservice and then querying the JSON it returns. Plain and simple you can't do this with a view. There is no work around there.

Comment: @SeanLange I know there is no workaround I was just wishing that my knowledge was flawed and someone out there had a solution, In the end I'll create a job and fill a table twice a day instead or tell the developers to query the web service directly from the application ;)

Comment: @PM77-1 Trying to feed a view with data returned from JSON fo the developers don't need to change the app

Comment: If the data doesn't have to be real time and refreshing it once or twice a day is acceptable then yes populate a table when you need to and create a view on the table.Or it needs to be realtime do it in the application or call your procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2017 you can publish an SSIS Package as a SQL View.

In this case when you execute a query on a view, SQL engine will start an SSIS package.
You have to use special SSIS destination: "Data Streaming Destination" to push data to a view. You can find more details in a walkthrough: [Publish an SSIS Package as a SQL View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/walkthrough-publish-an-ssis-package-as-a-sql-view?view=sql-server-2017)

In this solution you will need to created a linked server to a SSIS instance, but it will not be a direct DB to DB connection and you will use Web Service to get data, so it will meet your requirements. In the linked server you will use new OLEDB provider "SSISOLEDB".

To get data from a web service you can use custom C#/VB code or use some of the predefined tasks, like [Web Service Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/web-service-task?view=sql-server-2017) and then deserialize JSON.